# How to know when a user leave my website

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please i am trying to track users on my asp.net application, i want to know when a user leaves my web application either by using the log-out button or close the webpage totally.

Please any clue on what to do

Comment: The log-out button should be obvious of what you need to do

Answer (score 3):

You use `onbeforeunload` event for this.

See this [demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm).

Comment: I'm curious if you can send an AJAX call to record this on a server. Wouldn't the page unload so far that this would be impossible?

Comment: You mean so "fast"? I haven't actually tried logging everything but if it is not possible because the request will be cut off immediately, I am sure there are workarounds. Like saving in localstorage first and doing the request on next visit but this would require a revisit.

Comment: This solution is okay, but when i click a page on my website it popup the message which made it not suitable for my purpose